# How do I print \\ in java without one becoming an escape sequence character?

Tags: java

In IntelliJ, my code is something like this,

```
String m = "\\Hello";
System.out.println(m);
```

I want to print 2 backslashes but one always becomes an escape sequence. When I add another backslash (total 3 backslashes) it gives me an error "`java: illegal escape character`"

Answer (score 4):

Escaping characters is accomplished using a special symbol: `\`. In Java, a backslash combined with a character to be "escaped" is called *a control sequence*.

List of escaped characters:

- `\t` - tab.
- `\b` - backspace (a step backward in the text or deletion of a single character).
- `\n` - new line.
- `\r` - carriage return. ()
- `\f` - form feed.
- `\'` single quote.
- `\"` double quote.
- `\\` backslash.

So if you want a single backslash `\`, you need to escape it like `\\`. So two backlashes would look like `\\\\`.

---

#### What does your error mean?

When you have a string like: `"\\\hello"`, breaking it down, it means `\\`, `\h`, `e`, `l`, `l`, `o`.

`\h` is an not a valid escaped character. Which is why your error says `java: illegal escape character`.

Comment: Thank you so much!
Today I opened my code editor and when I typed //// it gave me // in the terminal and realised that I got the output I needed

Answer (score 1):

If you want one \ you have to type \\. If you want two \\ repeat it two times ;)

```
String m = "\\\\Hello";
System.out.println(m);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to store 4 backslashes in the string variable

```
String m = "\\\\Hello"; System.out.println(m);
```